# list of objects in an object

Tags: list, object, c++-cli

I'm new to C++ and this is my first program, so there can be some odd/strange codes that isn't logic at all for C++.

I'm working with Visual studio 2015 C++/cli and I'm trying to get an object list in another object.

LinePiece.h:

```
ref class LinePiece
{
    private:
    std::string* Type;
    int ElementNr;
    int Status;
    int X, Y, X2, Y2;
    int Diameter;
    std::string* Text;
    public:
    LinePiece();

    LinePiece(std::string* a_type, int a_ElementNr, int a_Status, int a_x, int a_y, int a_x2, int a_y2)
    {
        Type = a_type;
        ElementNr = a_ElementNr;
        Status = a_Status;
        X = a_x;
        Y = a_y;
        X2 = a_x2;
        Y2 = a_y2;
    }
};
```

Element.h:

```
#include "LinePiece.h"
ref class Element
{
public:
    Element();

    //properties
    std::string* ON;                        //order nummer
    std::string* MO;                        //order merk
    std::string* SN;                        //element nummer
    std::string* RS;                        //element afwerking
    std::string* OW;                        //wapeningspatroon
    std::string* CN;                        //element calculation number
    int el_length;                          //element lengte
    int el_width;                           //element hoogte
    int el_beginX;                          //element beginpunt
    int el_concrete_height;                 //element hoogte beton
    int el_iso_height;                      //element isolatie hoogte
    std::string* el_weight;                 //element gewicht
    std::list<LinePiece^>* listLinePieces;  //lijst met contouren   
};
```

So when I try to build this code, it gives the following error:

'&&' cannot use this indirection on type 'LinePiece^'

How can I solve this issue so I can get an object list with `LinePiece` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  std::list<LinePiece^>* listLinePieces;
```

When you are in Rome then it gets to be important to act like a Roman.  You cannot store a managed object reference in an unmanaged collection.  Storage for managed objects is taken care of by the garbage collector but it has no hope of finding those references back.  It doesn't know beans about the internal structure of an std::list and can thus never reliably find the managed object reference back.  The compiler must complain about it.

Use a `List<LinePiece^>^` instead.  Also much, *much* more efficient than an std::list and cliext::list.

---

```
  std::string* el_weight;
```

Much the same for all of those std::string pointers, you probably discovered the Hard Way that you had to store a pointer to them.  The C++/CLI compiler does not permit storing the value in the managed object, too dangerous when the garbage collector moves the object when it compacts the heap.  And you had to write a pretty ugly constructor to get them allocated.  That works okay now, as long as you implemented a finalizer (don't skip!).  But life in Rome is a lot easier when you make them a String^ instead.  So the garbage collector takes care of them.

Comment: When I'm using the `List<LinePiece^>^ listLinePieces` it gives the following errors: `'^': cannot use this indirection on type std::list<LinePiece ^, std::allocator< _TY>>` and `a handle to a non-managed class is not allowed`

Comment: You only did half the job.  You must get rid of std::list completely, change the declaration as well.

Comment: And what should I include to recognize `List` ?

Comment: Replace `std::list<LinePiece^>*` in your class declaration with `List<LinePiece^>^`.  And initialize it in your constructor with `listLinePieces = gcnew List<LinePiece^>;`  Put `using namespace System::Collections::Generic;` at the top of the source code file so that the compiler knows what List means.  There are lots and lots of maps of Rome, you'll greatly benefit from bringing one along.

Comment: Ah yes, I noticed it. Works much better, and sounds more logic for me (the `^` sign is still odd for me, since I'm used to C#). But I like the `System::String` more, since they can communicate with controls without converting them first. Thanks for the information and help @HansPassant

Answer (score 0):

You havent mentioned it but you are trying to use some specific C++/CX features, is it on purpose? If so I think you need to add a namespace as well, otherwise skip the `ref` and the `^`.

There is too little code to completely understand what you want to do, but I'd skip making pointers of all strings, I don't think that is what you want to do, but as I don't have the rest of your code I cannot be sure. Also, making a pointer of the list is probably not what you want either.

Comment: Well this is all I got at the moment, later on when I can create this list, I want to fill it by reading a file that gives me the information for these classes. For example this file is build up by elements and I get these information out of the file by reading the lines (for example The ordernumber is referenced as ON in the file) and later on there are lines that say CO X/Y begin value, X/Y end value. This is a linepiece object.

Comment: when I actually remove `ref` and `^` it doesn't give any errors. So how does this work? I'm used to C# and never used this icon before.

Comment: I guess the big question is, do you use .NET stuff in your project. If you don't I'd convert this to use STL instead, if you do go with Hans description above.

Answer (score 0):

Library STL / CLR contains in namespace cliext instead of std.

```
#include <cliext\list>
...
cliext::list <LinePiece^> listLinePieces;
```

I recommend to abandon the pointers to std::string in favor to System::String^ from .Net.

**EDIT:**

.Net also includes the implementation of a doubly-linked list. To use it:

```
#using <System.dll>
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
...
LinkedList<LinePiece^> LinkedList;
```

Read more on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx)